# How to make MFCC algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, detection, signal-processing, fft, voice

I wanna make the Mel-Frequency Cepstrum Algorithm but there are some things that I don't understand.

After FTT is done we need to "Map the powers of the spectrum obtained above onto the mel scale, using triangular overlapping windows."

I know how to calculate the triangles and I also know how to pass to mel scale.
I simply don't know what to do with them.

If the triangles are defined, how do I map the power of the spectrum obtained above onto the mel scale?

Is it like this:
Sum the frequencies inside the triangle and then pass it to mel scale?
or
Sum the frequencies inside the triangle according to a weight value (defined by the height of the triangle at that point) and then pass it to mel scale?
or
Pass all the frequencies inside the triangle to mel scale according to the weith value?
Another thing?

Can anyone clarifies this to me

Comment: My suggestion is to be a straightforward and gracious member of the community.  Stop posting under different user names (Andre, Andre Ferreira, and aF); thank people for their help on your previous three similar questions, and upvote and accept their answers if appropriate (this current question is clearly following my previous answers yet no acknowledgement or upvotes); and be honest (don't answer your own questions as though you're someone else).  For questions like these, it's a very small community.  Otherwise, pay someone to help you... would you like to know my rates?

Comment: I was unregistered and coudn't get any access after logout..
I really don't understand very well this part and I am gratefull to what you said till now.
So please, can you help me to understand it at all?
I allready read a lot of things but this part I really don't understand.

Comment: Sure.  1) The tagging of questions is very important.  I think to get more people to see your question tag it also with "FFT" and "signal-processing".  2) people on SO are motivated by helping people and to get points, so upvote things you like by clicking on the arrow by the question or answer, and accept the answer to your own question that works for you (click on the check, I think).  3) follow along on your own questions even after they're answered so people feel acknowledged.

Comment: 4) people take questions by people with some points more seriously, imho, so for this reason alone it helps you to not change user names all the time, and participate more broadly. 5) if you can, participate in the broader goal of SO by answering others questions (this will also help you get some points -- see 4). I think that's about it (from my perspective).  This is the type of thing you meant, right?

Comment: Thanks for talking about SO. Now I get it. I was with unregistered accounts but that won't happen again.
I didn't see how to vote for the answer and I only can give reputation for a question that I didn't asked.

Passing this, can you please help me understanding the algorithm.
Any of my ideas is right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this step of the process is a little weird and doesn't make complete sense (to me anyway).   The center of the filter bands are equally spaced along the mel scale, but are triangles on the linear scale, i.e. just like the figure [here](http://instruct1.cit.cornell.edu/courses/ece576/FinalProjects/f2008/pae26_jsc59/pae26_jsc59/images/melfilt.png).

Then calculate the weighted sum using these triangle along the linear x-axis.  (In this previous step, I think that some approaches normalize by the filter-triangle's area, and some don't, and I'm honestly not sure about the final consequences here, though I suspect it may not mean much except to modify the final interpretation which are all relative comparisons anyway.  One maintains total energy, and the other give equally weighted contributions per band.)  Then take the log of this (which converts the overall volume factor to an offset).

**Edit:**
To be more clear on applying the filters...  Each triangle represents a separate filter, producing a separate weighted sum.  If there twenty filters in your filter bank, there will be twenty triangles, and twenty weighted sums to calculate.  To apply each filter, for each x-axis value multiple the filter value at that x-location by the function value at that x-location, and add this to the sum for that particular filter.  Most x-axis values with have two filters that are present there, so at each x-location makes a contribution to two filters.

Comment: I edited my answer to address your question, I hope.  If it doesn't, please restate your question very carefully so I understand what's unclear.

Comment: Also, you can probably still accept my answer, even without 15 points. It's not like I'm dying to get the points here, it's honestly more to get you engaged, but see this...  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8396/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-where-do-i-click  But don't accept this for about a day anyway, so more people will see the question and maybe someone will have something illuminating to say.

Comment: Thanks again!
Offcourse I accept your answer.
You have been great to me.

The final doubt is regarding the conversion from frequency to mel scale.

This is made by applying the filters and the sum of weights?

or

I need to do something like this:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mel_scale
anywhere?

Comment: My understanding is that the Mel scale is just to determine the spacing of the filters in the filter-bank.  Once you have this spacing, the triangle-filters and the weighted sums that they lead to are done along the linear scale.

Comment: Yes, now is that what I think of it.
And with more then 15 points there is the vote. You earned it :P

Thanks a lot!! :d

Comment: Andre -  I'm glad to help, and I hope you do something interesting with the MFCCs.  Good luck with it.